# XPath expression to capture all nested text under a specific root

Tags: xpath, lxml

I have some HTML from which I want to extract text content using Python + `lxml`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Some text I DON'T want</p>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Some text I DO want</p>
      <span>
        <a href="#">A link I DO want</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Couple of conditions -

- I *only* want text nested under a specific root `div[@class='container']`
- I want *all* nested text under that root

So -

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    import lxml.html
    doc=lxml.html.fromstring(HTML)
    root=doc.xpath("//div[@class='container']").pop()
    for xpath in ["p|a",
                  "//p|//a"]:
        print ("%s -> %s" % (xpath,
                               "; ".join([el.text_content()
                                          for el in root.xpath(xpath)])))
```

then -

```
$ python xpath_test.py 
p|a -> Some text I DO want
//p|//a -> Some text I DON'T want; Some text I DO want; A link I DO want
```

So `p|a` captures too *little* (doesn't capture the nested link) whilst `//p|//a` captures too *much* (tags I don't want)

What xpath expression will return only `Some text I DO want; A link I DO want` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following XPath (all texts descendants from the specified `div` excluding whitespace nodes) :

```
//div[@class="container"]//text()[normalize-space()]
```

Piece of code :

```
data = """HTML
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Some text I DON'T want</p>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Some text I DO want</p>
      <span>
        <a href="#">A link I DO want</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
HTML"""

import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
print (tree.xpath('//div[@class="container"]//text()[normalize-space()]'))
```

Output :

```
['Some text I DO want', 'A link I DO want']
```